# Using yes with interactive script results in exit code 141

Tags: bash, printf, circleci

I need to run a command in CircleCI that will pass predetermined arguments to a following command. When the command only expects strings or integers it works fine to use:

```
printf "arg1\narg2\n" | my_command
```

But if "my command" expects a user to use arrow keys to select an option followed by the return key this method fails.

Here is an example of what I am describing:

```
? Which variation would you like to apply? (Use arrow keys)
❯ A
  B
  C
```

So I tried another option, having found a nifty tool called yes:

```
yes | my_command
```

This will actually work (and selects option A), but it results in a failed build in CircleCI due to the exit code 141. From what I understand, that exit code happens because yes is still sending input to a process that has exited.

Is there another way I can accomplish?

Comment: the same problem with Gitlab CI omnibus I had. I used `yes '' | npm login` command. it successfully logged in but pipeline failed with *error code 141*. changing code to `(yes '' || true) | npm login` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override the error by using double pipes to true.

```
yes | my_command || true
```

This works but it overrides any errors that the sequence might throw, making my CI tests evergreen. Which is not ideal, but it works.

Comment: There is a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57797492/11768

Answer (score 20):

```
(yes || true) | my_command
```

This way you ignore the result code from `yes` but preserve the result code from `my_command`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) - programmed dialogue with interactive programs